# How to pass multidimensional Numpy arrays to C function using CFFI?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cffi

I am trying to speed up my Python program by implementing a function in C++ and embedding it in my code using CFFI. The function takes two 3x3 arrays and computes a distance.
The Python code is the following:

```
import cffi
import numpy as np

ffi = cffi.FFI()
ffi.cdef("""
    extern double dist(const double s[3][3], const double t[3][3]);
""")
lib = ffi.dlopen("./dist.so")

S = np.array([[-1.63538,  0.379116, -1.16372],[-1.63538, 0.378137, -1.16366 ],[-1.63193, 0.379116, -1.16366]], dtype=np.float32)
T = np.array([[-1.6467834, 0.3749715, -1.1484985],[-1.6623441, 0.37410975, -1.1647063 ],[-1.6602284, 0.37400728, -1.1496595 ]], dtype=np.float32)
Sp = ffi.cast("double(*) [3]", S.ctypes.data)
Tp = ffi.cast("double(*) [3]", T.ctypes.data)

dd = lib.dist(Sp,Tp);
```

This solution doesn't work as intended. Indeed the arguments printed by the C function are:

```
 Sp=[[0.000002,  -0.270760,  -0.020458]
    [0.000002,  0.000000,  0.000000]
    [0.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000]]
 Tp=[[0.000002,  -0.324688,  -0.020588]
    [0.000002,  0.000000,  0.000000]
    [0.000000,  0.000000,  -nan]]
```

I have also tried the following to initialize the pointers:

```
Sp = ffi.new("double *[3]")
for i in range(3):
    Sp[i] = ffi.cast("double *", S[i].ctypes.data)
Tp = ffi.new("double *[3]")
for i in range(3):
    Tp[i] = ffi.cast("double *", T[i].ctypes.data)
dd = lib.dist(Sp,Tp);
```

But this solution rises an error in `dist(Sp,Tp)`:

```
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'double(*)[3]' must be a pointer to same type, not cdata 'double *[3]'
```

Do you have any idea on how to make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types `double[3][3]` and `double *[3]` are not equivalent. The former is an 2D array of double 3x3, stored as 9 contiguous double. The latter is an array of 3 double pointers, which is not how 2D static arrays are implemented in C or C++.

Both numpy arrays and C++ static arrays are represented in memory as a contiguous block of elements, it's just the `double *[3]` type in the middle that's throwing a wrench in the works. What you'd want is to use `double[3][3]` proper or `double[3]*` (a pointer to a row of three doubles). Note that if you use the latter you may need to change the function prototype to take `double [][3]`.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed casting to `double[3][3]` has worked. Anyway I had also to change the numpy type to `float64`